# Traversing the elements of BST

Tags: python, python-2.7, binary-search-tree

I have a binary search tree whose nodes are stored in a python dictionary. Here is an example:

```
BST = {'node1': ['Fail', 'node3'], 'node3': ['Fail', 'Pass'], 'node2': ['Fail', 'node1'], 'node4': ['Fail', 'node2']}
```

In the dictionary, every key is a parent from BST and the list (value of the key) is the children of that parent with corresponding key from dictionary.

For example:

```
BST['node1'] =  ['Fail', 'node3']
```

In this case, `'node1'` is the parent of the children `['Fail', node3]`. First element of the list, `'Fail'` is the left child of the `'node1'` and the other element of that list, `'node3'` is the right child of the `'node1'`.

The edge between left child and its parents has the value of 'yes', and the edge between right child and its parents has the value of 'no'.

`Fail` and `Pass` values are the leaves of the BST.

One observation, to be able to find the root; just pick a node and check whether is has a parent. If not, it is the root of the tree. Otherwise check the same thing with the parent of that node.

Here is the corresponding tree with the dictionary:

[image: tree with the dictionary]

I think the construction of the tree is clear. Now about my question, I need to find the paths in the format of having `FAIL` node as its final node and starting with a yes edge. If the first node  is not with yes edge, just eliminate it and look for the next one until the yes edge is found to be starting point of that path.

Illustrative example:

[image: example tree]

In this BST, valid paths should be:

```
[[node4,yes], [node1, yes], [node3, yes], FAIL]
[[node4,yes], [node1, no], FAIL]]
[[node2,yes], FAIL]
[[node1,yes], FAIL]
[[node3,yes], FAIL]
```

Note: If a path is found, no need to look at its sub paths. For example, this is not valid since there is longer path that covers this one:

```
[[node4,yes], [node3, yes], FAIL].
```

which is:

```
[[node4,yes], [node1, yes], [node3, yes], FAIL]
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: your example stuff confuses me ... why is node1,yes lead directly to fail? shouldnt it be node1,no - > fail?

Comment: In this case, if that node exists, then it causes fail. Why shouldnt it be?

Comment: Actually, I am not good at recursive function. I wrote lots of things then deleted them.

Comment: node1,yes seems to goto node3, not to fail... however node1,no goes to fail

Comment: Sorry, it is a mistake. There are some nodes with the same name. It should not be. This is the reason actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ugly, to implement the Tree with the `Dictionaries`, 
instead use the self referential structure `class Node` as mentioned below

```
class Node:
    """Referential Structure used to create new nodes"""
    def __init__(self, data):
        """Constructor."""
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

This will make your Traversal much easier

please refer: https://github.com/SivaCn/Small-Codes/blob/master/Python/BinarySearchTree.py

Comment: You are right, I also did not like using dictionary. I will try this method.

Comment: although you would want to add some methods to the node class ... if its just data members a class is rarely the right choice , however it is almost always the right choice if you want to combine data members and actions

Comment: I wrote some methods in that class and it works fine.